# How do I change the MaxLength of the PasswordBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to be able to change the MaxLength of the Password box based on another control. how do I change the passwordBox MaxLength when user clicks the toggleButton.

Below is the code I have for the toggleBox and PasswordBox but this is only allowing 1 as the maxLength when toggled.

`<PasswordBox  MaxLength="{Binding ElementName=toggleUseToken, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="textboxPassword" BorderThickness="0"  ToolTip="Enter your password" Password="password"  Style="{StaticResource textboxpassword}" Grid.Column="1"/>`

`<ToggleButton x:Name="toggleUseToken" Grid.Column="3"  ToolTip="Remember Me" Style="{StaticResource toggleToken}" Height="20"/>`

Comment: and how should toggle state relate to MaxLength? It's not clear from the post. Anyway it should be possible to do with the use of `Coverter`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, **why** do you want to change the maximum-length of a password field at runtime? The maximum length of a password should not be constrained like that - I hope it's not because you're storing passwords in plaintext....?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik, When the toggleButton is True the MaxLength should be set to 5 else 12

Comment: @Dai, when the toggle is enabled, the password box will take a token of specific length, when the toggle is disabled, it should take a length of 12

Comment: @cookiemonster 12 characters is too short for a password max-length - let alone 5 - again, **why** are you doing this? If you're accepting TFA credentials then those should go into a separate input box - don't re-use the same  input control for two different things.

Comment: It's a very bad practice to restrict user passwords by either length or characters. You shouldn't care about such details at all. Enforce a minimum length and complexity. And ensure the user's private data is safe. For this reason you should avoid collecting passwords in general. Use Windows authentication or an OAuth service.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <PasswordBox MaxLength="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButton, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource ToggleButtonToMaxLengthConverterKey}}"/>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" Content="Set Length"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And use Converter:

```
public class ToggleButtonToMaxLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool isChecked)
        {
            return isChecked ? 5 : 12;
        }

        return 12;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but am getting resource ToggleButtonToMaxLengthConverter could not be resolved eventhough I have added the reference in Window.Resources

Answer (score 0):

You could a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` to set the `MaxLength` property:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="textboxPassword" BorderThickness="0" ToolTip="Enter your password" Password="password" Grid.Column="1">
    <PasswordBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="PasswordBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource textboxpassword}">
            <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="12" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleUseToken}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="5" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </PasswordBox.Style>
</PasswordBox>
```

Comment: @cookiemonster: Did you try this?